# SQL Server sync size of variable used in stored procedures or functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, sql-server-2016, variable-length

We do create variables to store column data, like below

```
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(300)

    SELECT  @Name = Name,
            @Age = Age
    FROM [Employee]
```

Here, we give size as `VARCHAR(300)` in a assumption that length defined in table is `300`.

And this happens across store procedures.

What if the size is increased in table ? (eg. 500). 
Is there a easy way to update the size across stored procedures ? or any better way of creating variables ?

Comment: How often do you change table structures to increase column widths?

Comment: Maybe in initial development phase we make many changes, that too if its a big distributed team, we never know someone made this change in DB

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like ORACLE [`%TYPE`](http://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-041.html):

> The Oracle %TYPE attribute adapts code as table definitions change. The %TYPE attribute provides the datatype of a variable or database column. If the column's type changes, your variable uses the correct type at run time. This provides data independence and reduces maintenance costs.

**Microsoft SQL Server does not support and has no an equivalent of Oracle %TYPE.**

SQL Server does not suppport this mechanism. Possible solutions:

- declare your variables with length more than 300
- use [user-defined datatypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql)

Comment: user-defined datatypes are initially appealing until you realise that you can't change the type definition (there is no `alter type`, and you can't even `drop` and `create` if the definition is actually in use elsewhere)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, this is big drawback of user-defined types.